# How to get no of days left in quarter

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me to get the number of days left in the quarter from current date in SQL

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Note that an RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational data. Consider handling simple (date) arithmetic in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create quarter end date and then do `datediff` as follows:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) 
                 + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER 
                 - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
               CURDATE())
```